# how to load .so file that are not in System/lib folder in android?

Tags: android

I have a so file named `libJSA.so` in memory card in android and wanna load it in my application.

How can i load this file using `System.loadLibrary("libname");` ?

Things i have tried:-

- try to copy it to `/system/lib`.    ----   Not worked
- `System.loadlibrary("/mnt/sdcard/folder/libJSA.so");`     -------- Not worked

Answer (score 1):

```
System.loadlibrary("/mnt/sdcard/folder/libJSA.so"); // Not working
```

try:

```
System.loadLibrary ("JSA.so");
```

not (java is ase sensitive):

```
System.loadlibrary("JSA.so")
```

or instead try

```
Static{
    System.load("/sdcard/folder/libJSA.so");
}
```

put this inside the class and outside `onCreate`.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, unless it's a system library or you are on a rooted device, you can't load any libraries that are outside your signed APK bundle, meaning what you want to do can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

`System.load("/mnt/sdcard/folder/libJSA.so");`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing "lib" prefix.
If your library name is "libJSA.so", try to use `System.loadLibrary ("JSA");`